# Django ORM: filter by conditions on related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have the following schema:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    ...
```

Given some complex filter on Client objects, I want to find all their Invoices. For example all Invoice of Clients, that contain letter 'a' in their address:

```py
Invoice.objects.filter(
    Q(client__name__icontains='a') | 
    Q(client__country__icontains='a') | 
    Q(client__city__icontains='a') |
    Q(client__street__icontains='a')
)
```

But I don't want to keep all the details of the filtering logic in this place. Ideally I would like to have a separate function that contains all the filtering logic, for example:

```
def get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a():
    return Q(name__icontains='a') | Q(country__icontains='a') | ...
```

Perfect, now I can filter companies like this:

```
Client.objects.filter(get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a())
```

But I would also like to use it to filter Invoices, for example:

```
# does not work:
Invoice.objects.filter(company=get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a())
```

And also Products on the Invoices of the same Companies:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)

# does not work:
Product.objects.filter(invoice__client=get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a())
```

So far I figured out I could do some prefix string concatenation, i. e.:

```
def get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a(prefix: str):
    return Q(**{'{prefix}name__icontains': 'a'}) | 
        Q(**{'{prefix}country__icontains': 'a'})) |
        ...
    
# ugly, but works   
Product.objects.filter(get_client_filter_for_contains_letter_a(prefix='invoice__client__'))
```

Is there a better, clean, preferably object-oriented way to do it?

Comment: What part about it is ugly to you? You could break up the logic into a few other components. One to do the prefixing, one to order the list of fields together, one to return the list of fields that are for the business logic's searching functionality.

Comment: First, models and fields in ORM are object-oriented and this approach is based on plain string concatenation, so it just "feels" out of place. I don't think this is a very unique issue, I thought maybe there already exists a standard mechanism for dealing with this.

Comment: Second, throughout the system I have multiple models like Client, where I would like to apply this approach. Each of the filters is complex, touching multiple fields, so there would be 100s of string prefixing operations scattered throughout the system.

Comment: And third, having this scattered in multiple places, in case of any change to the models I would have to go rewriting a bunch of strings all over the place. If this was done using some form of query-object-builder, I think introducing changes to models could be easier.

Comment: In my experience, I've built them as needed. There's likely something out there, but I haven't searched. Try checking https://djangopackages.org/